# Facebook Product Share

Tags: magento-1.9, facebook

I added

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=&t=', 'facebook',
>   'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');"
>   title="__('Share on Facebook') ?>">Facebook

for product share on facebook. Everything works fine but image not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below og details to your product details page:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Your content to share on facebook" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/media...productimage.jpg" />
```

Replace description and image url with your product description and image.

For more guidance you can refer the below link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags

Add the below code snippet to your **head.phtml**

```
<?php 
 $_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );
?> 
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $_product->getog_title() ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $_product->getog_image() ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo Mage::registry('product')->getProductUrl(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $_product->getog_description() ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
```

Comment: where i add this afater by sahre code?

Comment: Under head tag of product details page.

Comment: can you give little breif code? because i have sahringfile.phtml

Comment: Wait! I am posting the code.

Comment: <a href="javascript:popWin('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($_productUrl ); ?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($productName); ?>', 'facebook', 'width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Share on Facebook') ?>">Facebook</a>
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo  urldecode($_productImageUrl) ?>"/>

Comment: this is my code

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Dont use meta details in your body.

Comment: and put share button where

Comment: In your page according to your requirement. Facebook capture the image from og tags

Comment: i have check inspect element it shwos but when i share still image not showg

Comment: Which element is showing? Og tags? If yes then wait for sometime it should work or try on private browser.

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: Are you working on local server or live server?

Comment: Check here if everything is fine or not? https://opengraphcheck.com/

Comment: showing opengraphcheck.com heere

Comment: This can happen due to several different reasons such as your server using unsupported content-encoding. The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings.

Comment: there? now images share but when i refresh 2 3 times

Comment: So its working now?

Comment: yes but one issue is that when i sahre it first time its come without image but when i refrest it then image show

Comment: I think this is something with caching issue. Try to clear all cache or check it in private browser.

Comment: magento cahe is disabled and pvt same not show image first time

Comment: the product which i already sahred if i shared again then its show first time

Comment: this i found  When content is shared for the first time, the Facebook crawler will scrape and cache the metadata from the URL shared. The crawler has to see an image at least once before it can be rendered. This means that the first person who shares a piece of content won't see a rendered image:

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug your url here `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/` where you can find error on your url. After added your url you have to click on `fetch new information` or `scrap again`. In facebook if one time product shared then it's data cached in facebook so you have to click on "scrap again" button for get updated data. Thanks.